# How to download & install "COMODO" antivirus for Ubuntu 14.04 Lts

Tags: system-installation, antivirus

*Downloading and installing is not like windows in ubuntu. If we want to install something then we can only install from Ubuntu Software center or Terminal. But, I have been fed up, I tried but i am not getting command to download and install "comodo" antivirus by terminal and Comodo is not available in "ubuntu software center. If I am downloading Comodo from Comodo website, then I will not be able to install it further. But in window we can install anything by clicking right button and that file will install.*

**Please help and make me download and install COMODO antivirus for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

I am looking best help from Gentle persons. I will really appreciate any help regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, you really don't need an antivirus for Ubuntu unless you're planning on dealing with windows files and/or systems.

You can download Comodo Antivirus from their website, and choose your architecture 32bit or 64bit. Once downloaded, just press Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded (probably the Downloads folder), and run the command(s) below:

> sudo dpkg -i file_name.deb

I would recommend ClamAV. To install run in terminal

> sudo apt-get install clamav
>
> sudo freshclam
>
> sudo clamscan

or you can use https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clamav/

Comment: I am on the link Provided by you.  What to do now please tell me in details. I on link " https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clamav/"

Comment: Use the download button then the ubuntu center pops up then you can download from there

Comment: I have already installed it, how to use it.  I am searching for CLAMAV in search but i am getting clamtk